# Plain JavaScript execution in Firefox/Internet Explorer after browser navigation

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8

In IE8, history navigation (back/forward) causes code to be executed on the onload handler.

How can I get Javascript in Firefox to also execute after a back or a forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `window.onunload = function(){};` after the execution of you onload handler. See *@fig-gnuton's* answer in [After travelling back in Firefox history, javascript won’t run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run).

Comment: Cheers, that did it! Sorry about the dupe, my search did not find it.