# history.back(); doesn't trigger $(document).ready();

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, browser-history

I have a webpage that use `$(document).ready()` to build the interface. Then the user can go to a child page, and to go back to the original page he can press the browser's "previous" button or a "Return" button in the page which triggers a `history.back();`. Back on the original page, `$(document).ready()` is not triggered so the page is missing information.

Is there a way to trigger it automatically like if it was a "real load"?

**edit**

placing an alert in it, the alert is popped but stuff is missing in my interface like if some part of the ready event is missing. Investigating...

**edit 2**

hahahahaha in `document.ready` I `click` some checkbox which are supposed to be unchecked. When I "back" on this page, they are checked so they become unchecked because I re`click` them.

Sorry, this is completely my bad :(

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in? I recall only Opera having this problem with the back/forward buttons.

Comment: I'm on Chrome. The user that reported the problem is on Firefox.

Comment: Its a Firefox feature, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run

Answer (score 28):

A quick solution to this problem, use "onpageshow" instead.

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    //do something
};
```

Comment: Thanks! None of the other proposed solutions worked properly on both Firefox and Chrome, but this one does.

Comment: Thanks! I have noted, that $(document).ready() not is triggered with history.back(); on mobile browsers (safari and google chrome) under iOS , (whereby it works on desktop.browsers) and have searched a long time... with window.onpageshow it works on all browsers

Comment: warning, pageshow does not fire on iframe elements on firefox 74, but "load" does =/

Comment: Warning, history back is sorcery! Let's join together and remove its funkyness forever, only thing it should really do is to re-fill previously-filled forms. That's all, otherwise it should load normally x)

Answer (score 7):

If the user uses the `Back` button to navigate and you require a full reload of the page, you can set the `NO-CACHE` policy of the page.

This way the browser is forced to reload the page from the server, even using the `Back` button.

Comment: Hrmm..nice answer. Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I already use: header("Cache-Control: private, no-cache, must-revalidate"); header("Pragma: no-cache");

Comment: I added `<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">`, but it doesn't reload the page when I press "back".

Comment: Depends on your browser - google chrome doesn't handle it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

1.) put scripts at the bottom of your page.
2.) execute plugins and whatnot in your last script tag(s).
3.) Do not use onDomReady implementations at all, it's redundant.

People are so accustomed to onload or ondomready, they overlook the fact that putting your scripts at the bottom of a page does virtually the same thing without the need to poll and see if your html is available.

Furthermore, it's also good practise as your scripts do not block html/css rendering either.

Not depending on onDomReady or onLoad implementations solves a lot of issues.

Comment: -1, For a browser where `onload` doesn't work, your solution doesn't work as well. E.g. FireFox, it just doesn't run the script regardless of whether you put it in onload or at the bottom of the page. Did you even test?

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question. You might need to re-trigger the event/function when the page gets focus, or something similar. you might also need to keep a flag variable to track whether an 'event re-triggering' is in order.