# JQuery .ready when clicking browser back button - desktop browsers vs IPad browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have this simple code on a page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
alert(“works”);
    });
```

Then I go to the next page, I click in the browser back button and it doesn’t fire the $(document).ready, but if I return to previous page by a link it does.
Tested on desktop browsers and no problem but doesn’t work on Safari or Chrome on IPad

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What does (or does not) happen on the iPad?

Comment: @Pointy  The event is not triggered when i return to previous page by back button

Comment: This is hard to believe to be true - that would mean the hundreds of sites my company has built have document ready functions that do NOT work on a "back" click....

Comment: The issue is that exactly the same code works on desktop but no on Ipad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [history.back(); doesn't trigger $(document).ready();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628536/history-back-doesnt-trigger-document-ready)