# window.onload not triggered when user navigates but does when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have a Chrome extension with a content script that must be injected when the url matches the rule. the thing is, if I refresh the page, it's working, but if I navigate to the url (it does match the pattern) then the event is not triggered.

Any idea why?

Edit: Take into account that it's based on a web app and I've tried using the `webNavigation` event and still doesn't work.

Edit: Ok, so a working solution (in Chrome at least) is to use the [onHistoryStateUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) event handler.

Comment: Showing us your code would help...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly due to the cache saved in your Browser. If you hard refresh it, then it will run the whole script again.
You can use the following code:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```

You can also try this function:

```
window.onpageshow()
```

Comment: I cleaned my browser's cache and still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried it opening in a new browser which is never used?

Comment: No. It's a chrome extension.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628536/history-back-doesnt-trigger-document-ready but it still doesn't work :S