# Load jQuery click events, even when using back button (Squarespace)

Tags: jquery, squarespace

I'm trying to hide and show paragraph's on a FAQ page. The paragraphs are hidden initially, and I add the following code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('h3').click(function() {$(this).next("p").toggleClass("unhidden-paragraph") } )
  })
```

`unhidden-paragraph` styles it to show the paragraph. So if one clicks on a question (`h3`) then it shows the paragraph.

This works perfectly, however when I go to a different page on squarespace and then use the back button to my FAQ page. Then the `ready` is not called again and clicking on the `h3` questions no longer works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [history.back(); doesn't trigger $(document).ready();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628536/history-back-doesnt-trigger-document-ready)

Comment: @Mohammad that question has no solutions that actually work. Or at least with squarespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute some jQuery setup code even when the user enters the page from the back button, you can use `$(window).on('pageshow')` instead of `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(window).on('pageshow', function(){
    $('h3').click(function() {$(this).next("p").toggleClass("unhidden-paragraph") } );
});
```

---

For "single-page" designs (a la Squarespace), you might have to just attach the method to the `onclick` attribute of the HTML element directly:

```
<h3 onclick='$(this).next("p").toggleClass("unhidden-paragraph");'>Title</h3>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work, when replacing the `$('h3')...` with `console.log('test')` for testing it shows that it is actually never run when you access the page via the back button.

Comment: Does your Squarespace site use a single-page design?

Comment: Yes, it does, single page application.

Comment: @Otto Check my edit, see if it'll fit for your case.

Comment: @Otto glad I could help!