# HTML5 onpopstate on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the new HTML5 onpopstate event. Using Firefox 4 the window.onpopstate event is triggered on a page load whilst in Webkit this does not seem to be the case.

Which is the correct behaviour?

Comment: This is fixed in Chrome Canary now, and presumably it will be fixed in the next version (or two) of Chrome.

Comment: @Agamemnus, Weird, doesn't fire on page load for me.

Comment: Under what conditions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The popstate event is fired in certain cases when navigating to a session history entry.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#event-popstate

From my understanding, though I could be wrong, seeing as loading the page does mean history is created and traversed to, yes, it should be fired on page load.

Also see,

http://www.mail-archive.com/whatwg@lists.whatwg.org/msg19722.html

and,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: There seems to be so e ambiguity between Firefox and Webkit on this one. Currently, Webkit does not fire onpopstate during a page load.

Comment: **For developers visiting this page after 2011**  The HTML5 specs were modified such that 'popstate' should never be fired on the initial page load. FireFox, IE10, etc. all exhibit the correct behavior; Chrome (and probably Safari) do not.  **Please up-vote https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040 to get Chrome back in compliance with the standard**.

Comment: @Dave: Safari Mobile still (Aug 2014) fires this on initial page load.

Comment: @Dave, It has been fixed long ago https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040#c47

Comment: @Dave: Could you please post a link to w3c spec that says popstate event should never be fired on page load? I can't find anything about that...

Comment: I said it should never be fired on the *initial* page load. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/browsers.html#history-traversal - steps 12-14. There's an explanation of this at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040#c50 as well.

Answer (score 4):

Firing onpopstate on page load is correct, and WebKit will have this behavior soon. WebKit 534.7 (Chrome 7.0517.44) now behaves this way.

I filed a Chrome bug on it, but it turns out this is the desired behavior; it is needed in order to handle certain back/forward button actions correctly. See [this bug report at code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040) for more discussion and links.

I'm still trying to come up with a good code pattern for an onpopstate event handler.

Comment: Had this problem too (onpopstate firing for webkit giving a double page load on first load). I got around this by adding some logic - e.g. only adding onpopstate listener after first ajax request.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if is this what you are asking, but my solution for an *ajax-only* onpopstate event handler is to set up to `true` a variable `refreshed` on `window.onload` and set it to `false` on `history.pushState` calls; then on the `onpopstate` handler just do stuff if `refreshed` is `false`.

Looks silly, and it is, but I couldn't do any better.

Comment: In Firefox, `window.onload` is also triggered when browser's Back button is clicked, so it's probably better to initialize `refreshed` some place else.

Answer (score 3):

Just solved this issue, and the fix is actually quite simple. Firefox doesn't fire onpopstate on initial page load. After you fire a popstate, return false or prevent default on the page.load action, and you're golden.

Cheers.

In action here: www.thecoffeeshopnyc.com

```
// Write in a new handler for Firefox, which does not fire popstate on load.
// Modern Webkit browsers fire popstate on load. The event handler below fires the controller
$(window).load(function () {
    if ($.browser.mozilla) {
        // Your func.
    }
})

// Add the event listener. If the above is false, it will still run as intended in normal browsers.
window.onpopstate = function() {
    // Your func.
}
```

Comment: This will break when Chrome decides to fix this problem. Browser detection is a fast way to fix things, but feature detection should be used to avoid hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 1):

> Browsers tend to handle the popstate event differently on page load.
>   Chrome and Safari always emit a popstate event on page load, but
>   Firefox doesn't.

This quote was taken from Mozilla's documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate

I tend to agree with the Mozilla system.  Page load is not an action that requires an extra popstate event to be fired, because the state is not being popped, it is being loaded for the first time.

I am guessing Webkit is doing it for convenience... in all my implementations, it is consistently an inconvenience to delay loading my handler until after the initial popstate has fired.

Instead of this (using pseudo functions):

```
AddEventHandler(window, 'popstate', OnPopState);
```

I have to do something like this:

```
AddLoadEvent(window.setTimeout(function() 
    { 
        AddEventHandler(window, 'popstate', OnPopState); 
    },0));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested, I've came up with a decent pattern for working with `onpopstate` (this code assumes jQuery, feature detection checks are stripped for clarity):

```
$(function() {

  // 1. Add initial state to current history record on page load.
  var href = location.href;
  history.replaceState({"href": href}, null, href);

  // 2. Now attach the popstate handler.
  window.onpopstate = function(ev) {

    // Raised on page load this event will still contain no state.
    var state = ev.state;
    if (state && state.href) {

      // 3. Add your logic, use `state` and `state.href` as you see fit.          

    }
  };

});
```