# onpopstate in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

I use **pushState** and **onPopState** to create ajax navigation.

But there is a tiny problem here.

In first visit to the page or on page refresh chrome fires onPopState event but firefox doesn't.

This leads to chrome loading the content twice, but firefox works well.

I don't know which one is working correct and how can I solve this?

It seems that this behavior was opposite in older versions :))

[HTML5 onpopstate on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700440/html5-onpopstate-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) 
{
    if (!event.state) return;
    ajaxPage(document.location.href);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This did not work in an earlier Safari version for me.
We can implement our own window.onpopstate with a domReady listener if

- we won't use it before the dom is ready
- Chrome's initial onpopstate was fired before

The general problem is Chrome here :

The current HTML5 specs say that 'popstate' should never be fired on the initial page load. Chrome and most Safari versions do not follow that. 
Chrome Team should take notice - please "star"

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040