# History.js vs. window.history for HTML5-only mode

Tags: html, browser-history, pushstate, history.js, html5-history

Does History.js offer any substantial advantages over HTML5's `window.history` nowadays? We're not interested in supporting/falling back to the HTML4 hashbang URLs.

History.js [doesn't support anchors in `pushState()`](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/173), while `window.history` does. We need this feature so if there are no big reasons to use History.js instead of the native `window.history` in HTML5-only mode, we'd rather go for the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - on their website they say:

> Provide a cross-compatible experience for all HTML5 Browsers (they all implement the HTML5 >History API a little bit differently causing different behaviours and sometimes bugs - >History.js fixes this ensuring the experience is as expected / the same / great throughout >the HTML5 browsers)

Those differences are small, and googling wasn't enough to find them - I had to look in the source code - it seems that the main one is fixing the HTML5 functionality in safari.
There are two problems with the safari implementation - one is that history.back fails to return to a hash state set by location.hash which is susequently replaced by history.replaceState.

The second is that when busy safari will fail to apply state changes.

Relevant History.js source code:

```
    History.bugs = {
        /**
         * Safari 5 and Safari iOS 4 fail to return to the correct state once a hash is replaced by a `replaceState` call
         * https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56249
         */
        setHash: Boolean(!History.emulated.pushState && navigator.vendor === 'Apple Computer, Inc.' && /AppleWebKit\/5([0-2]|3[0-3])/.test(navigator.userAgent)),

        /**
         * Safari 5 and Safari iOS 4 sometimes fail to apply the state change under busy conditions
         * https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42940
         */
        safariPoll: Boolean(!History.emulated.pushState && navigator.vendor === 'Apple Computer, Inc.' && /AppleWebKit\/5([0-2]|3[0-3])/.test(navigator.userAgent)),
```

So I guess your decision comes down to whether you care about Safari 5 and Safari IOS 4.

Comment: Thank you for the useful research. The Safari bugs aren't a dealbreaker for us so we're sticking with the native `window.history`. There are browser differences, however (the most notable one being [when `window.onpopstate` is called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700440/html5-onpopstate-on-page-load)) so we've had to code around those.