# How to handle ready and pageshow events across all browsers, to help when back button pressed

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, browser-cache

I'm new to jquery, and only just realised that code in the `.ready` function does not always get run when you return to a page using the browser's BACK button. From reading two-year-old posts on stackoverflow it appears that not all browsers work in the same way, and there is no single jquery function to solve matters. **Is that still the case?** What is the best method (in 2012!) for detecting whether a page is being run for the first time, or being shown again after the user has pressed BACK?

Just to be clear: imagine I had a page of red text where clicks changed words to blue with javascript/jquery......if I navigated to a new URL, then pressed BACK, the following would happen:
Firefox - words still blue
IE/Chrome - words gone back to red

**Firefox**
I understand Firefox and some other browsers implement the `pageshow` and `pagehide` events and do not fire the `ready` event when showing a page from the 'bfcache'. Within this function you can check `event.originalEvent.persisted` [to see what the situation is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648745/11461).

**IE/Chrome**
[I am aware of one trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button/10842561#10842561) that uses `<input type="hidden" id="dirty">` to keep track of whether a page is loading for the first time in IE/Chrome. Not sure how reliable this is. I could also try a cookie I guess.

Apologies for complete ignorance...

**Edit: Why do it?**
My own situation would take ages to explain, but here's an inane example that has the same problem: Image a page that shows 10 playing cards, and the user can pick a card to make it move upwards on the screen. When you pick a card, an ajax request fires to send the card's details to the server. Now imagine you navigate away from the page, then use BACK to return to it. Three things can happen:
 1. The browser may call the server to get the page, and the server (database) knows which card was chosen, so can output the relevant HTML/script
 2. Firefox will use the bfcache to show your page - the chosen card will still be selected (moved upwards) as the state of the DOM was exactly preserved (the `ready` event will not be hit)
 3. IE/Chrome will reload the original HTML from the cache and call the `ready` event's script.....showing all the playing cards in the 'unselected' position. Your chosen card is lost!

Comment: What behavior are you looking to implement that would require this feature? If some sort of state change is happening, should the request not be made with post to prevent this exact sort of situation? Just asking....

Comment: I see what you mean, but no, this should be GET not POST. I'll edit the question...

Answer (score 1):

you can use this snippet to check if page comes from bfcache (back-forward cache)

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.persisted) {
        // comes from cache
    }
});
```

Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

A ready function is initialized after a page download has complete, Going back in history is going back to a page that's already in a loaded state.
Make sure your code is in a function so you can attach it to an event handler such as this one:

```
//A function to execute
function updateCardDeck() {
 ...
};

//The event call bind
window.addEventListener('pageshow', updateCardDeck, false);
```

This is probably the event you want to use after a history browse action and you should put this at the bottom of your HTML mark-up and not inside a window.ready event.

Comment: Firefox does this, but I don't believe IE does...?