# Execute document.ready even if user came to the page by hitting the back button

Tags: jquery

I have a PHP page with jQuery's `$(document).ready()` which does some changes to the form on the page. This works fine. But if I come to this page and then went to another and then hit 'Back' from the browser and came back to this page, the `$(document).ready()` function does not seem to run at all. This is happening on FF as well as Chrome.

Is there some way I can have `document.ready` executed even if the user hit the browser's back button to come to my page?

Comment: It might be you forms have autocomplete on

Comment: Two years ago, couple of seconds searching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run

Comment: @Musa, this happens even if there s no form used at all. Basically the document.ready function wont fire if the page was visited by hitting the back button of the browser :(

Comment: @Alfabravo Thank you! That works :) Can you please post that as an answer as well? I ll close it then

Answer (score 25):

I had exactly the same problem; @Alfabravo's link helped me a lot here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648785/679240

The code below worked okay enough for me, since what I actually needed was to do some cleanup either when the user entered the page or when the page was reached through the back button:

```
$(window).on('pageshow', function(){
    console.info('Entered the page!');
});
```

If you need to specifically detect specifically when the page was reached through *the back button* but not when entering it the first time, you may need to control a bit of state; the link above may help you there.

Comment: This is a great way to prevent an action from beeing done while clicking the back button. I used this to block the "loading page..." div based on $(document).ready if the users is coming from the back button (because the page is already loaded as it is in the cache).

Answer (score 4):

My use case is that, when hitting the back button the `ready` event is fired and my handling function executed just fine.

In spite of this I found that some of my page data was still stale.

I put in some `console.log()`s to assert that all functions were in fact being called.

For my particular situation, when the page is loaded some AJAX is called to load some data from my server. I found that it was, in fact, **the response from the API that was being cached!!!**

Of course it was!

My solution, then, was simple.

I added a newly generated timestamp

`new Date().getTime();`

as a query parameter to the AJAX call's URL and voila, the data returned was fresh.

Comment: FYI this technique is well known and it's called cache busting

Comment: This post that reminded me the contents of the AJAX response could be cached as well, so thank you from the future.

Comment: To the recent editor of this answer: Thank you for trying to improve it but I found that your edits mostly just removed my attempts at humor. This being a socialized platform I see no reason to avoid personality in answers so long as the core content is practical. If you were a Futurama fan, maybe you would have been more amused. I respectfully ask you to refrain from further edits.