# Method to detect page came from back button

Tags: javascript, zepto

I made a method to show a loading indicator at the bottom of the page when a link is clicked.

When someone hits the back button, it doesn't refresh the page content of course thus showing the loading area.

Is there a way to detect whether the page came from a redirection to fire a method to remove the loading indicator?

Kinda like so:

```
function cameFromeBackButton(){
    //hide loading indicator
}
```

**OR** is it a way to stop the back button and fire a method instead? like so:

```
function  backButtonClicked(){
    //do stuff instead of going back
}
```

**EDIT:** This is pretty much how the area is being called

```
$('.link').click(function(){
 //make loading area
 $('container').append(loadingAreaString)

 //grab the href and goto page
 window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');

 return false
})
```

Comment: Can you just prevent the cached version of the page showing or do you WANT the cached copy to show but still fire certain things?  If so http://blog.55minutes.com/2011/10/how-to-defeat-the-browser-back-button-cache/

Comment: Seems like a sever side solution right? In my case this all needs to be client side. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: How is the function that shows the loading incicator called?

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer from server some token and store it in cookie or local storage. When stored token is different from token embedded in page - this means page was loaded from server, if values are equal - this means page was served from cache (or from back button).

Comment: Tried to do that but it doesn't read the storage when I hit back.

Comment: here is answer to how force JS run after back button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run