# Refresh page on back button press

Tags: javascript, html, session, back-button

I saw the other questions/answers related to this issue, but I couldn't find anything that explains it clearly.

I want to know if there is any JavaScript code that refreshes the page when user presses the back button. Like in Facebook or Gmail, when you perform a log-out then press the back button, nothing happens; the page gets refreshed.

I created a web project and when the user performed a log-out, then the session is terminated and it is redirected to the index page. But if the user wants he can go back through back button and see the information again.

Comment: This link is not about javascript, jsp, java. Just general talk

Comment: you're right, im sorry for starting the close vote train :(

Comment: At the other side it does not respond to my question about something like facebook or gmail

Comment: Thank you rambo, I really searched a lot for a solution for this but no one till now has been clear

Comment: I did a general search on something among the same lines of your question and so far all of them are very clear: you don't use javascript to prevent the user from going back, you change your response's caching policy so they are **alwyas** requested from the server.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that? or if you may please post the link

Comment: @AlbanoVito, I don't have a full answer for you, but I think you could force some js to be executed by studying [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run) and the bfcache behavior. You could use that to re-request the content from the server, and let cookies or whatever be the deciding factor of whether content gets served.

Comment: It is not what I am looking for, thank you for your answer anyway. I will search on my own and I will respond if I will find something

Answer (score 2):

If you tell the browser to not cache the page it will request it again when they press the back button.

Comment: I have to tell the browser no to cache all the pages within the website or is there any way to tell the browser to delete the cached content?

Comment: @AlbanoVito, I don't know of a way to delete the browser's cache.

Comment: I do not want to bother you but please explain a little more if you can. So it is the first choice? I have to tell the browser not to cache all the pages?

Comment: @AlbanoVito, yes.  There's a *lot* of discussion about that in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers).

Comment: That question was for 2008 and maybe it worked back then but I just tested in Firefox 18, IE 8 and Chrome 24 and I was able to go back and see my pages again after making the changes in my code

Comment: @AlbanoVito, I would guess that either the page was already in your cache or you chose the wrong answer.