# Django/FF issue with form template loading

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

When I submit the form (eg: below), url gets redirected to `localhost:8000/test/result/`, and I get some result. This step works fine.
However, when I click on browser back button to go back to the initial form, Firefox doesn't load the form, although url has changed to `localhost:8000/test/`. I get a blank page. Also, if I click the back button again, it takes me to `localhost:8000` page. Chrome and IE works though.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this FF issue?
Many thanks in advance.

```
#---test.html---
<form id="input-form" action="{% url test.views.main_view %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
...
</form>

#---views.py---
class MainView(FormView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    form_class = UserInputForm
    success_url = 'result/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...

#---urls.py---
urlpatterns =  patterns('test.views',
    url(r'^$', view='main_view', name='main-view'),
    url(r'^result/$', view='result_view', name='result-view'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2638292/1428653) is the issue. Failing that, something that will definitely work is setting your Cache-Control header to “no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store” – but that's a nasty brute force solution.