# Back button and a custom scroller, why aren't they acting the same on two webpages?

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, back-button, scroller

I am using the [malihu custom scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) on a website, and I can not figure why it doesn't react the same way in the demo and on my website.

[demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html)
[website](http://www.beauchesnearchitecture.com/realisations/view)

Steps :

1. Scroll down one custom scroller (doesn't matter how much)
2. Go to another website or click on a link
3. Hit the 'Back' button

Demo : goes back to where it was.
Website : goes back to top of list

Deactivating the custom scroller plugin solve this specific issue.

Any idea why?

Comment: It does **not** go back to the last scroll location when I try the demo site, navigate away and hit back.  All the scrollbars are at the top of their respective content.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 30. And hum wow, I can't belive I didn't do tests in differents browsers, the demo only works in FF...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this on the following browsers:

- IE9
- Chrome 35
- FF 30 (Same as OP)

As the OP said, this only works on FF.

FF has a feature called `Back-Forward Cache` which remembers the entire state of the page, even the js states.  This occurs for the duration the browser stays open. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching).

If you don't want to have this occur for experience reasons, there are other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run) about it on stackoverflow.

---

### Update

If you read the documentation for the `Back-Forward Cache`, it states that it won't work if you have the `Cache-Control: no-cache` response headers, which you do have enabled.

[image: Caching disabled]

This is causing the browser to get fresh data each time instead of caching images and pages locally for faster browsing on later visits.

Comment: You do not provide any informations about why it would work on the demo page and not on the other page. And I actually want it to happen.

Comment: Congrats, you earned it. :)