# handle js execute, when history back

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, browser-history

I found some article in stack overflow about browser bfcache, 
I test in safari Version 7.0.5 (9537.77.4), when I click history back the js won't execute, How to use window.onunload or other method, handle js if not execute due to cache, make it execute?

```
window.onunload = function(){
  alert('window.unload');
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    // js app
});
```

Comment: have you tried using `window.addEventListener` as detailed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload)?

Comment: yes, I saw this reference, but I can't understand how to combine to use? Can you show example for me?

Comment: if you'd bothered to click the link to the `addEventListener` reference page, you'd see an example. there should also be plenty online.

Comment: I'm confusing should I put my application into unload callback?

Comment: Of course not! The whole point is, you attach the event handler through the DOM event system instead of the node properties. It is the recommended way to do it and it should work better. there's even an answer with this exact thing ffs!

Comment: ?? so how do I make if click history js not execute, force to execute?

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(){
  alert('window.unload');
});
```

Comment: Should I put my application into unload callback function? is it make if history back, js will still execute?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: ?? so how do I make if click history js not execute, force to execute?     like this: window.addEventListener('unload', function(){
  // page all js
});

Comment: The answer was post prior to the question was edited. Please refer to the edit before voting down the answer.

Comment: OP seems to be looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run