# Append div using Ajax call works only in the first load

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, domdocument

I'm using YQL + jQuery to get the content from a remote page, I'm able to load the content in the **1st** page load but after clicking the page menu to **return back** to the same page the div not appended.

I was able to achieve the **refresh** using ele.html(ele.html()), my code is bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#divAjaxLoading").show();
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v...",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (data) {
        var result = $(data).find('results').find('.content');
        //debugger;
        $('#Home_CP_Home').html(result);
        $("#Home_CP_Home").html($("#Home_CP_Home").html());
        $("#divAjaxLoading").hide();
    }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: What is `results` in your `.find('results')`? `results` is not a valid selector as there is no HTML element called `results`. Is it a class or id maybe?

Comment: He may have registered a custom HTML element. Though that's not likely the case...

Comment: Results is an attribute of **YQL** which contains the HTML content I need (div element from remote page).
i.e: <results><div class="content"><div class="wide_page_columns"></div></div></results>

Comment: Is this the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run

Comment: @CyrilDD how can I know I appended a custom HTML div?

Comment: @Tarik you just gave the answer two comments above :P

Comment: You can use other ajax functions i.e. `$.get`, `$.post`, `$.ajax` instead of `$().load`. After getting response in success callback, just append that to your div using `$('#Home_CP_Home').append(result);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm using ASP.NET project the control had attribute runat="**server**" after making it a normal html div by removing that attribute, I got div appended after postback.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your result is from a pure XML, it's a XmlDocument implementation and contains XmlElement implementations.

Your page is a HtmlDocument implementation and interpret HtmlElement, not pure XmlElement.

Option 1, transform your Document to a string and let jQuery parse it has an HtmlDocument:

```
success: function (data) {
    var result = $(data).find('results').find('.content');
    $('#Home_CP_Home').html(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(result[0]));
    $("#divAjaxLoading").hide();
}
```

Option 2, walk the XmlDocument to create same elements in HtmlDocument:

```
function convertHTML(input, output) {
    switch (input.nodeType) {
    case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        var i;
        var newelt = document.createElement(input.tagName);
        for (i = 0 ; i < input.attributes.length ; i++) {
            newelt.setAttribute(input.attributes[i].name, input.attributes[i].value);
        }
        for (i = 0 ; i < input.childNodes.length ; i++) {
            convertHTML(input.childNodes[i], newelt);
        }
        output.appendChild(newelt);
        break;
    case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        output.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.nodeValue))
        break;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Then use it:

```
success: function (data) {
    var result = $(data).find('results').find('.content');
    convertHTML(result[0], $("#Home_CP_Home").empty()[0])
    $("#divAjaxLoading").hide();
}
```

Comment: The 1st option works only on the first load after postback using page menu it doesn't work!

Please can you review option 2, Nicolas.

Comment: Is there no problem using convertHTML(result[0], $("#divAjaxLoading").empty()[0]), Nicolas ?

Because I don't see a use of $('#Home_CP_Home').

Comment: You right, I replaced #Home_CP_Home by #divAjaxLoading > fixed

Comment: Thank you

I used option 2 it works well in the 1st load but after postback it still shows spinner but without appending div with it's content.