# How can I trigger beforeunload warning when refreshing but not when submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-refresh, onbeforeunload

Page 1 contains a dynamic form, page 2 is a review of submitted data.  I have the following constraints :

- no `beforeunload` warning when submitting page 1 ;
- `beforeunload` warning when refreshing page 1 ;
- <s>no reloading of page 1 when issuing `history.back()` from page 2.</s>

I tried to play with `window.onbeforeunload` and `$(window).unload()` (in page 1) but I can't seem to get the expected result.

Is this even possible, or are these constraints definitely contradictory (I mean, for a reasonable number of JS lines…) ?

### Update :

I removed constraint 3 because according to some reading it deserves [its own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37376683/812102).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this for parts 1 and 2, not sure what you mean with part 3 though

```js
"use strict";
var isSubmit = false
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  isSubmit = true
  window.location.reload()
})

window.onbeforeunload = e => {
  if (!isSubmit) {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave?"
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Indeed it does the trick for constraints 1 and 2, thanks, but not for constraint 3.  I'll try to rephrase : unload shouldn't be triggered when going back from page 2 to page 1.  It seems to be the default behaviour, but when the JS code includes `onbeforeunload` or `unload` page 1 will be refreshed when coming from page 2.

Comment: [This answer of another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2639165/812102) is related — in other words, I need bfcache to be enabled even though I use `onbeforeunload` and `unload`.

Comment: I'll accept this answer and edit the question to remove constraint 3, which I will ask about in another question, since it seems to be too specific.