# why jquery is not hidding content when we press back button in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I am showing a random carousel on my index page. It works just fine when we refresh but there are some items on my page which redirect the user to another page when the user clicks on the back button to go back on `index.html` both carousel show up.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  if (random === 0) {
    $('#myCarousel').show();
    $('#my3').hide();
  } else {
    $('#my3').show();
    $('#my3').show();
    $('#myCarousel').hide();
  }
});
```

Why the jQuery is not working in this scenario?

Comment: Would need a more complete example here to see what's going on.

Comment: AFAIK, hitting the back button does not cause the page to re-run javascript.  If you want script to run on a back button, you have to do something with a popState event on the window, or something of that nature.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: you can see here web.kyetees.com:4200  click on some items and then you will redirect to another page . then click on back button to go index.html you can see two carousel. thats the error

Comment: @ThisisFish What browser are you using? Anyway, I suppose regardless of browser a similar fix applies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run

Comment: @Taplar would using IIFE wrapper make any drastic changes in this situation?

Comment: I don't believe so?  The issue is the code does not inherently get re-evaluated again.  So using or not using an IIFE, as far as I can think of, wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: i tried everything you guys suggested . it won;t work at all.i dont know what to do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 carousels on your page and you use this JS to randomly show one or the other.

*«hitting the back button does not cause the page to re-run javascript»*, as Taplar correctly said in comments. Now it seems like the page is returned to its state as it was before the document ready handler is executed...

---

**EDIT**

Since the `.remove()` trick isn't working either...

I would try to use **only one** slider. But based on the random number, replace or not the image slide set.

So you have to have the image replacements in an array.

```
var replacementImageArray = ["assets/img/4.jpg", "assets/img/1.jpg", etc...]
```

Then on document ready, check the random number and proceed with replacement...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  if (random === 0) {
    $('#myCarousel').find("img").each(function(index){
      $(this).attr("src", replacementImageArray[index]);
    }
  }
});
```

Disclaimer: the script above is an untested suggestion... Just as a strategy hint.

---

Bonus, a code "cosmetic" and performance hint:

```
if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
```

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1)

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: And with just the CSS ? Making sure only one of the two is showing (regardless of the JS) should do... You tried?

Comment: when i use your css logic. it works fine but it always show only one carousel.

Comment: its an angular project . i haven't got this type of error when i work with js,html and css only