# After History Back, Scroll to Top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code in my Web app to go back a page:

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

It works well, but it takes users to the same vertical location they were on the page. After going back, how can I have the TOP of the page being shown instead?

I tried:

```
<script>
window.history.go(-1);
window.scrollTo(0, 0); // This doesn't execute.
</script>
```

I don't need smooth animations or transitions. The key is just making sure the command runs after going back.

Comment: You need to call `scrollTo(0,0)` on page load of the page that is the target of the back click.

Comment: I tried that. But since users are being sent to the page on a history back, the page load is not triggering and the scrollTo(0,0) doesn't take effect. If it was a regular page load, that would work.

Comment: what's the `return false;` for?

Comment: The DOMReady function should still fire, though.

Comment: @Argee Not needed, removed from my question.

Comment: Does the user press any button to go back or simply the javascript handles it? If the user presses it, you could send them to link to a page which automatically takes them to top of the page rather than using a back button.

Comment: hi, have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run/12648785#12648785 ?

Comment: @keidakida The JavaScript handles it automatically. It's a tricky question, I know. It looks easy, but the implementation is not straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after trying several things these are the only two that worked for me.

### jQuery

```
$(window).on("pageshow", function(event) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

### JavaScript

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This method works on Firefox though, not in Chrome. You can refer to this question [After travelling back in Firefox history, JavaScript won't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run) for more details.
You can use this code in first_page.html:

```
<script>
    window.onunload = function () { };
    scrollTo(0, 0);
</script>
```

The onunload with make sure the scrollTo(0, 0) is executed even if the back button is pressed or even if you use window.history.go(-1);

Comment: I need to support Chrome. Is it somehow possible to do in Chrome?

Comment: Would see if there is any work around it. But can't promise it.

Answer (score 0):

Use history.scrollRestoration:

```
if (history.scrollRestoration) {
  history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
history.back();
```

Profit!

[scrollRestoration at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration)