# Get current time in JavaScript when the browser retrieves a cached html page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm having a html-page which is cachable. At the end of the page, I put:

```
<script>
    console.log(Date.now());  
</script>
```

I load the page: The console shows 1695306780514.
I follow a link on that page.
I press the back-button of the browser.

My assumption was that I now get the current datetime, a little bit later than the previous one.

But:

- Chrome (on Windows) shows the same 1695306780514, not the current datetime in console.
- Firefox (on Windows) shows just nothing in console.

I even tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(Date.now());
});
```

or

```
var showDate = function(){
    console.log(Date.now());
};
window.setTimeout(showDate, 1000);
```

but the effect is exactly the same.

How can I make sure the javascript is executed again and uses the correct datetime?

Comment: The Back button doesn't necessarily re-fetch the page, so it doesn't execute the scripts.

Comment: What browser are you using? [Here is an old question on this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run) It's *really* old however, and so the answer(s) may not be relevant in 2023.

Comment: https://web.dev/bfcache/

Comment: When pages are loaded via bfcache or popstate, the original javascript is not run - it's only run when the page is first loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the bf cache in action.

You can listen to event.persisted and force a reload if necessary:
https://web.dev/bfcache/

Comment: Thanks! This lists the possibility of using window.addEventListener('pageshow', (event), which seems to work execalty like I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the hints to https://web.dev/bfcache/. The solution is to use the pageshow-event, which is shown there. Adapted to my problem:

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', (event) => {
  console.log(Date.now());
});
```

This works fine.