# Safari browser ignoring my no-cache

Tags: asp.net, safari, pragma, no-cache

I'm unable to force a page to always expire in Safari.  Chrome, IE and Firefox are good citizens but Safari is cruising along just fine with ignoring the following ASP.NET code:

```
// Expire immediately
Response.Expires = 0;
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: I've found a hint to the problem here: http://www.projectseven.com/extensions/info/safaribbfix/index.htm.  Apparently Safari doesn't treat the back button the same as other browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Believe it or not, the way to make Safari always reload the page was simply to add this to the body tag:

```
onunload=""
```

I found a mention of this here: [Is there a cross-browser onload event when clicking the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)