# Why doesn't Safari honor my cache-control directive?

Tags: safari, cache-control

There is a particular page that I would like the browser to always load, particularly when the user presses the browser back button to get to it.

So I use the following 'Cache-Control' directive in the header for this page (taking the PHP directly from my code).

```
$headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0';
```

This works for FF, IE and Chrome, but Safari (5.0.1) seems to ignore the directive and fails to reload the page (across multiple users, so it doesn't seem to be a setup specific problem). Searching hasn't revealed any known bugs, so I'm assuming there is something amiss on my end.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Update: just found this answer on SO.

[Safari browser ignoring my no-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384935/safari-browser-ignoring-my-no-cache)

Haven't tried it yet, but looks promising. Very strange that it is an addition to the body tag, so Im skeptical.

Comment: How exactly are you sending these headers?

Comment: Actually, WordPress is sending them. I am adding them by using a WordPress filter hook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to include the following attribute in the body tag to force Safari to reload the page:

```
onunload=""
```

As in:

```
<body onunload="">
```

I found this here: [Safari browser ignoring my no-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384935/safari-browser-ignoring-my-no-cache)

Which in turn got it from this thread: [Is there a cross-browser onload event when clicking the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)

Comment: as of 9/19/2020, this fix is no longer working. I have submitted the bug to the Apple community support [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251817133).

Answer (score 3):

Also see this Webkit bug report:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71509

I am experiencing the same issue, and it appears to be to be a bug in Safari.