# Using No Cache Headers, Safari still allowing page view of account after logout

Tags: php, safari, logout

When a user logs out of my site, they are taken to logout.php. After the sessions are destroyed, they are redirected to a new page. If the back button is pressed, they are taken back to account.php, and user information on the page is still displayed. However, if I hit refresh, the page then recognizes that no sessions are set and the page is locked out. I need the page to display no information when the back button is pressed, and cannot use JavaScript to do this. This problem seems persistent in Safari.

Here is my logout.php:

```
// *** Logout the current user.
$logoutGoTo = "../login/index.php?i=logout";
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$_SESSION['CM_Username'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['CM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
unset($_SESSION['CM_Username']);
unset($_SESSION['CM_UserGroup']);
if ($logoutGoTo != "") {header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
exit;
}
```

Here is the PHP headers that I have placed. I found these from another posting on this site:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

As I stated above this code does not work in Safari, it works fine in Chrome and FireFox.

How can I fix this problem using only PHP?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you could look at this post : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602887/why-doesnt-safari-honor-my-cache-control-directive

Comment: Before starting the session clean the earlier buffer and then try ob_start and clean