# jquery hover menu and back button

Tags: jquery, menu, hover

I have this code, but when I click the back button in the browser the menu is still visible and it's class still is 'show'

```
$("#courses > a,#masterclasses > a,#the-team > a").click(function (e) {                                                            
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('#courses > a,#courses-nav').hover(function(){
    $('#courses-nav').addClass('show');
    $('#courses > a').css('color','#43b2b0');
},function(){
    $('#courses-nav').removeClass('show');
    if ($('body').hasClass('courses')) {
        $('#courses > a').css('color','#43b2b0');
        }
        else {
        $('#courses > a').css('color','#000');
    }
});
```

I have tried adding this...
$('#courses-nav,#masterclasses-nav,#the-team-nav').removeClass('show'); 
...but that doesn't fix the problem.

Thanks for any help in fixing this issue.

C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, when you use the back and forward buttons, today's browsers don't actually reload the page. Instead, they keep the old page in existence, hide it when leaving, and re-show it when re-entering the page. This results in much faster back/forward navigation, and means that the page will be in the exact same state when you go back to it as it was when you left it. [About the bfcache](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Working_with_BFCache) in Firefox.

You can catch the `pageshow` event and use it to cancel intermediate operations without going so far as to break the bfcache completely (which is usually done by adding an `unload` event handler).

For hovers you may be better off using normal CSS `:hover` rather than scripting. It's only IE6 this doesn't work with. There again, hover-menus have quite tricky usability and accessibility problems whether done with script *or* CSS.

Comment: Found some for information on this here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button

Comment: Yes... though jQuery no longer breaks the bfcache like it used to in 1.3.