# jquery pageshow for IE?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load javascript using jquery .live() and binding it to pageshow. However, this doesn't work with IE (figures!), is there a compatible event I can bind to for IE?

```
$(".root").live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    alert("HERE");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mypage').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
```

it should work

Try to give id instead of class name of element u are referring for `pageshow`

Comment: I tried adding this and it still doesn't work: 

<body>
    <div id="mypage">
     <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" class="root">

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10842561/11461) by 'thorie' to a similar issue. His idea of checking a hidden field (dirty bit) works in IE and Chrome. Then you add in a seperate line to work in Firefox; bind to `pageshow` and check `event.originalEvent.persisted`.

I may be two years too late to help you, but hopefully someone else may find this of use (or I will be corrected for my idiocy perhaps?!).

Answer (score 0):

The pageshow event is not recognized by IE, it wont fire. JQuery already has the solution, the ready handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //your code })
```

or the shorter version, which is the same thing

```
$(function(){ //your code })
```

If you really want to use pageshow in a cross-browser way, trigger it from within ready

```
$(function(){
     $(document).trigger("pageshow")
})
```

and handle the pageshow event using your handler

Comment: The 'ready' event is not the same as 'pageshow' - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching