# pageShow event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $( function() {
        window.onload = function () {
            alert('This page was just hidden:');
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body pageshow="alert('Done');">
<div id="mypage" data-role="page"  data-theme="b"> 
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>This is page 2.</p> 
    </div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

But the `pageShow` event is not firing in IE. Any idea why?

Comment: when do you ever call `pageShow`? what is a `pageShow`event?

Comment: I read it from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_firefox_1.5_caching#Introduction

Comment: are you running this page in firefox only?

Comment: No i have to run it in ie also.

Comment: so that command will only work in FF. just use onload -- OR since you are using jQuery, use jQuery load events...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509688/jquery-pageshow-for-ie

Comment: @ibhbuhbuhb: Are you intending to accept, or indicate why any of the answers do not meet your criteria?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using 'pageshow' to have the JS excuted when clicking the browsers back button. You can use the 'unload' event to do this in IE and all other browsers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OnPageShow and OnPageHide are [new HTML5 event attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp), and as such will only enjoy limited browser support (at the time of writing)

Its more likely that later versions of incumbent browsers will support it. Firefox certainly will, as will Safari according to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_firefox_1.5_caching).

I couldn't find anything that stated it definitively, but I would say that its likely that these events aren't supported in the version of IE that you are using. Can you maybe post this information for clarification.

Hope this helps

Comment: 404 on your w3schools.com link above.

Answer (score 8):

Your code is inconsistent. You're using `jQuery.ready`, `onload`, `onpageshow` at the same time. Seems like a good place to start your refactoring process.

What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: Agreed. What the heck are you actually trying to accomplish? +1

Comment: Its possible its a learning exercise. They might be wanting to achieve nothing more than a greater understanding

Comment: yeah, or just give someone +50 bounty and the Benefactor badge to himself

Answer (score 5):

It is a mispell; in the body's tag, the name of the event is "onpageshow" and no "pageshow".

```
...
<body onpageshow="alert('Done');">
...
```

For IE pageshow event is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery code never gets executed. You should run it from within jQuery's "ready" event:

```
$( function() {
    $('#mypage').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        alert('This page was just hidden: ' + ui.prevPage);
    });
});
```

Comment: @ibhbuhbuhb: Can you move your jQuery code into the `<head>` of the document?

Comment: You mean ready event. $(function() {}); is shorthand for jQuery ready.

Answer (score 1):

PageShow event is not supported in older versions of Internet Explorer, which is most likely the problem that you are having.

Comment: Looks like it is supported in IE11 and Edge.

Comment: Ah ok. Guess I should have clarified that it isn't supported in older versions of IE.

Comment: I already gave a very detailed answer on how to support older browsers. Note that IE8,IE9,IE10 are basically not supported by Microsoft after Jan 2016 so depending on project you might be able to avoid supporting them - see http://www.computerworld.com/article/2490996/microsoft-windows/microsoft-slashes-ie-support--sets--huge--edict-for-jan--2016.html - and you should at least edit your answer to update it to the correct info.

Comment: Didn't realize I could edit my original posts... I updated it just now.

Answer (score 1):

From my tests:

- IE8/9 does not support pageshow/pagehide
- Chrome12 fires them but doesn't appear to have a page cache - they behave the same as load/unload
- FF4 supports them as expected
- iOS on iPad supports them as expected

Answer (score 0):

Do away with `window.onload` and `pageshow`. Whatever you want to be executed on window load, body load or page show put them in `$(document).ready()`, they will be executed serially once the page has been loaded.

Comment: $(document).ready() does not fire when the page is done loading, it fires when the DOM is..well..ready. $(window).load() is the equivalent of using <body onLoad="..">

Comment: Yesh Yesh! But thats the best place to put your code which needs to be executed once page has loaded (DOM is ready).

Answer (score 0):

i'm using FF 4.0.1

your pageShow event won't fire even in this.

[click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_firefox_1.5_caching)

for more information

**Update:**
`pageShow` fire after `pageLoad`.

it's better to use `onLoad`.

`pageShow` should be `onpageShow`

Answer (score 0):

The pageshow event doesn't work in many browsers e.g. if using WebView or UIWebView within an App on mobile.

Instead you need a four pronged attack:

1. `onfocus` occurs when desktop pages and some mobile pages come back to life
2. `pageshow` occurs when iOS Safari comes back to life - but not UIWebView
3. `visibilitychange` occurs when Windows Mobile IE11 comes back to life     - see http://daniemon.com/tech/webapps/page-visibility/ and try http://jsbin.com/runed/4 Edit: Looks like IE11 on WP8.1 now supports the pageshow event.
4. `webkitRequestAnimationFrame` detects if page inside Mobile App comes back to focus. Workaround needed because window.focus, visibilitychange and pageshow events don't work in Android apps (WebView) or iOS apps (UIWebView).

Code might look like:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', pageAwakened);
window.addEventListener('pageshow', pageAwakened);
window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    !document.hidden && pageAwakened();
});
if (window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame && (/^iP/.test(navigator.platform) || /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
    webkitRequestAnimationFrame(webkitWake);
}

var lastTs;
function webkitWake(timestamp) {
    if ((timestamp - lastTs) > 10000) {
        pageAwakened();
    }
    lastTs = timestamp;
    webkitRequestAnimationFrame(webkitWake);
}

function pageAwakened() {
    console.log('awakened at ' + (new Date));
}
```

If you wish to support <= IE8 or documentMode <= 8 then need attachEvent for focus.

Edit: Note that most modern browsers (including desktop IE11 and desktop Edge) support the pageshow event.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){ //your code })
```

Is the shorthand for $(document).ready(). document.ready fires just after the DOM is loaded, adding a window.onload inside it is unnecessary.

IE wont fire a "pageshow" event, since it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?! After 4 years?! The facts were correct at the time. Pageshow showed up in IE 11!