# How to retain/maintain collapse and expand states of <p:panelMenu> even after a page refresh?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Suppose I have the following simple `<p:panelMenu>`.

```
<p:panelMenu style="width:200px">
    <p:submenu label="Contents">
        <p:menuitem value="MenuItem1" url="SomeURL" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:menuitem value="MenuItem2" url="SomeURL" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:menuitem value="MenuItem3" url="SomeURL" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
    </p:submenu>

    <p:separator />

    <p:submenu label="Users">
        <p:menuitem value="MenuItem1" url="SomeURL" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:menuitem value="MenuItem2" url="SomeURL" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:menuitem value="MenuItem3" url="SomeURL" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
    </p:submenu>                
</p:panelMenu>
```

Once a sub menu is expanded should remain expanded until it is explicitly collapsed even after a page refresh.

Similarly, sometime later, if the sub menu is collapsed should remain collapsed until it is explicitly expanded even after the page reloaded/refreshed. Is this possible?

---

By the way, the following script expands a `<p:panelMenu>` by default (all `<p:submenu>`).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-panelmenu-content").css("display","block");
    $(".ui-panelmenu-header").addClass("ui-state-active");
    $(".ui-icon-triangle-1-e").removeClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
});
```

And the following script expands the first sub menu of `<p:panelMenu>`, if it is collapsed.

```
var isMenuExpanded = jQuery('div.ui-panelmenu-content.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-hidden').is(':visible');

if(!isMenuExpanded)
{
    jQuery('.ui-panelmenu-panel a').first().click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set every value item with ids
and also with class to the click response

```
<p:panelMenu id="menu" style="width:200px">
    <p:submenu id="submenu" label="Contents" styleClass="submenu">
        <p:menuitem id="menu1" value="MenuItem1" url="SomeURL" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:menuitem id="menu2" value="MenuItem2" url="SomeURL" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:menuitem id="menu3" value="MenuItem3" url="SomeURL" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
    </p:submenu>
</p:panelMenu>
```

---

set localstorage as global variable (index)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    localStorage.param=Number(0);
});
```

---

variables session with localstorage javascript

```
var param= Number(localStorage.param);
```

every page refresh, get the localstorage variable session to change the menu state

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var e1 = document.getElementById("menu_submenu");
if(Boolean(param)==true){
    e1.style.display="block";
    e1.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].className="ui-widget ui-panelmenu-header ui-state-default ui-state-active ui-corner-top";
    e1.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].className="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s";
}
else{
    e1.style.display="none";
    e1.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].className="ui-widget ui-panelmenu-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all";
    e1.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].className="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e";
}
```

the click event to set the localstorage variable session

```
$(document).on("click", ".submenu", function(e) {
var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
while (target && !target.id) {
    target = target.parentNode;
}
if (!(target.id == 'menu1')){
    var n= Number(param)==Number(0)?Number(1):Number(0);
    param=Number(n);
    localStorage.param=Number(n);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p:panelMenu stateful="false"></p:panelMenu>
```

`stateful` attruibute default is `true`. If you want to control collapsed/expanded states by hand, you should set it `false`, then you can use `expanded` attribute on submenu elements.

Answer (score 0):

Ways to store the current state of your panels (which are open and which are closed) are already covered pretty nicely with [this earlier Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234707/reload-or-maintain-dom-state-using-jquery-after-browser-back-button-pressed).