# Force page to refresh/reload if user clicks on back button in browser

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-browser onload event and the Back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)

How can I force a view/page to refresh when a user clicks browser back to that page?

Answer (score 1):

use **`onunload`**

```
<body onunload="alert(unloading page')"></body>
```

Comment: didn't work for me on Firefox...