# Run JavaScript after every time page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a simple question but its haunting me since many days  and I couldn't find the solution.
I would like to fire a JavaScript event for every time the page is loaded or rendered.

Can any body please help?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`?

Comment: just type "how to catch page load event with javascript" to google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function function_name() {
               alert('loaded');
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="function_name()">
        <p>hello</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Although the best way would probably be to use jQuery's [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to ensure browser compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `<BODY onLoad="alert('hello world!')">`

See some drawbacks and workaround on this thread: [Is there a cross-browser onload event when clicking the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)

[EDIT] or better (?), use:

```
window.onload=function() { 
   alert ('hello world');
};
```

(from [this thread](http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3921969.htm))

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onload = function(){/*your code*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your reqirement is such that the script needs to execute after the page has loaded completely you could write it in the following way

```
$(window).bind('load',function(){
    //your code here
});
```

document.ready works when the page html elements are loaded... the above code executes after the entire page (with its styling and images etc.) hence i believe that this requires a seperate mention