# jQuery: submit() not working on history:back

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm using jQuery's submit() method to do some basic form validation before the user is sent to the next page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function() {
        // form validation, set errors_detected = true on errors

        if(errors_detected)
        {
            alert("error");
            return false;
        }   
    });
});
```

The problem is that if the user has passed the validation and clicks the Back button in the browser, the jquery code stops working. I'm using Opera.

Comment: What browser is this happening on or is it all?

Comment: Read this link. Might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button

Comment: Rohan, have check the solutions offered and it does not work. But at least the problem - browser caching - is identified.

Answer (score 0):

Because usually when the user hits the back button, the browser shows the cached copy of the page, and doesn't run the `$(document).ready()` stuff again, AFAIK.

Not sure of the best way around this. Maybe setting a no-cache header?

Comment: Setting no-cache header using php didn't work either. Maybe this is Opera only bug.

Comment: Yes, this is an Opera 11.52 bug. Tried it in Chrome 15.x and everything works as intended.