# Back button on Safari/Webkit loading a page from cache instead of a fresh copy

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, safari, webkit

I am having problems with regard to a "strange" behaviour of Safari/Webkit on Mac OSX systems that's related to the functionality of the back button **while having javascript disabled** on the browser.

The scenario I have is a web application which consists of a login page that upon a successful login, would lead the user to page1. If the user logs out of page1, then he/she will get redirected to page2. Out of session and un-authenticated requests to page1 are being redirected to the initial login page via a 302 HTTP Response.

It's also worth to mention that responses to requests to page1 have the following HTTP headers present in them to prevent browsers from caching the page:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 1 JAN 1970
Pragma: no-cache
```

Upon a successful log out from page1, the user get redirected to page2. If at this point intime the user decided to click on the back button, then the browser will load page1 from its cache rather than hitting the server again to retrieve a fresh copy. **Please not that this all happen while javascript is DISABLED within Safari, having it ENABLED produce the expected result of reloading page1 from the web server thus having the user get redirected to the initial login page**

I've tried to set an unload event handler on the page body tag to prevent Webkit from having  the page loaded into its Page Cache, but that didn't seem to solve the problem.

Other mainstream browsers, FF, IE and Chrome seem to produce the expected result both in JS and non JS situations.

Am I missing something here or this sounds more of a bug with Safari/WebKit?

Cheers;

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the Page Cache feature in Webkit/Safari. You can find more information about this on the below link

[Problems with Page Cache in iOS 5 Safari when navigating back / unload event not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988967/problems-with-page-cache-in-ios-5-safari-when-navigating-back-unload-event-not)

As a quick fix, You can try adding an empty function to the window unload event. When this is present, Webkit/Safari won't add the page to the pageCache –– leaving the page to load normally like the other browsers do.