# When the client gets to a page by hitting the back button, how to make it load a fresh copy instead of cached one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, refresh, browser-cache, back

I'm trying to get a page to load a fresh copy from server when the client arrives at it by hitting the back button. By default it loads the old cached copy from browser memory.

Is there a way to do that? (in node.js)

Adding an empty function to `window.unload` [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17342116/1266650) doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tried all the Meta tags, they have no effect. But
the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)
referred to
[by @BenJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589771/when-the-client-gets-to-a-page-by-hitting-the-back-button-how-to-make-it-load-a/24589823#24589823)
mentions "when you don't have access to the web server's headers"..
I actually do have access to and can set whatever headers from server-side.
SO I dug [out this answer which worked flawlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429592/no-cache-in-a-nodejs-server/20429914#20429914)

```
res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
res.header('Expires', '-1');
res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
```

Comment: I tried this with res.redirect --> it does not seem to work on Chrome Version 61. 

router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('jwtToken', '', {expires: new Date(0)});
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.header('Expires', '-1');
       res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    res.redirect('/vendor/login');
});

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using these in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

**Update**

refer to this question on SO: [Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)