# How to prevent reloading of web page from cache while using mobile safari browser?

Tags: javascript, ios, caching, safari, pageshow

Mobile Safari uses a special caching mechanism `Page Cache` ([here](https://www.webkit.org/blog/427/webkit-page-cache-i-the-basics/)) which basically keeps the current page alive but hibernated when we navigate to another page. This way, it can immediately display the previous page in its latest state when user presses `back` button.

This is useful for navigation and browsing web but for special cases this becomes annoying as you may need to get a fresh copy of the page each time user navigates to that page. (in my case I have to pages: login and main page).

I am totally aware that nothing prevents user from opening multiple tabs of the same application. I not concerned about that.

The [cross browser solution for preventing page from being cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) does not help as Safari is keeping the page open but invisible and suspended.

The [window.onpageshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988967/problems-with-page-cache-in-ios-5-safari-when-navigating-back-unload-event-not) and handling `event.persisted` does not help as it seems that the browser does not execute `onpageshow` event for some reasons the second time (when you press `back` button).

**Note** for those who do not know what `onpageshow` event is about: Apple discourages using `load` and `unload` events because with the concept of **page cache** those events does not make a clear sense. So, `onpageshow` is supposed to do what we expect from `load` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user presses back button, you will receive the same document as you had before (the old page which was suspended). So if you handle `onpagehide` event and do some modification to the page just before navigating to the new page, your changes are kept there.

I tried adding a script block to the `body` just before navigating:

```
if (isSafari) {
        window.addEventListener('pagehide', function(e) {
            var $body = $(document.body);
            $body.children().remove();
                $body.append("<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.reload();<\/script>");
        });
    }
```

this does not work because the script **immediately** executes where my intention was to execute it when user returns back to the page.

**BUT** if you postpone your DOM modifications after leaving `pagehide` callback, (something like this):

```
if (isSafari) {
        window.addEventListener('pagehide', function(e) {
            var $body = $(document.body);
            $body.children().remove();

            // wait for this callback to finish executing and then...
            setTimeout(function() {
                $body.append("<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.reload();<\/script>");
            });
        });
    }
```

**TADA** it works! as soon as user presses back button on the next page, Safari loads the suspended page and executes this new block of script which has not executed before.

Comment: Instead of `$body.append("<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.reload();<\/script>");` why not simply do `window.location.reload()`?

Comment: Well...if you `window.location.reload` it does not work. (Was not working) if i remeber correctly safari does not load the page correctly or drops the whole reload. We need to run the script when page resumes after suspension

Answer (score 4):

Another potential solution is to look at the `event.persisted` flag to determine if it's cached or not:

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
    }
};
```