# IOS 9.3 disable back forward cache on iphone back button

Tags: javascript, php, ios, iphone

When a user logs out I'm trying to suppress the back button from rendering the previous page.  The code seems to work but I notice on a iphone the previous page is displayed for a second or two before it's replaced with the logon screen.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Here's the JS I'm using in the form

```
 window.onpageshow = function(event) {
     if (event.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
     }
 };
```

and then in the control file I simply use:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))  
    redirect("login.php");
```

I also tried the iframe solution but found that didn't work at all:

```
<iframe style="height:0px;width:0px;visibility:hidden" src="about:blank">
    this frame prevents back forward cache <!--doesn't work -->
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the following (suggested elsewhere, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783386)

```
document.body.style.display = "none"; // insert this line, before the next
window.location.reload();
```