# Run animation on clicking Browser Back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Please, is it possible to run an animation on the click of a browser button? And how?

I know it is possible with some Ajax manipulation, I believe.

Here is what I have now.

I got two divs with the class **.wrapper** both a 10% and sitting side by side in a parent div called **.flatbed**, width 1000%.

(Only one **.wrapper** class is revealed at a time.)

Now, when I click **#new_workspace** (*a button*), this happens

```
$('#new_workspace').click(function()
{
    $('.flatbed').animate({left:'-100%'}) 
});
```

This sends the first **.wrapper** class to left, out of the browser's viewport and reveals the second **.wrapper** class.

I reverse this animation with

```
    $('#back_to_workspace').click(function()
{
    $('.flatbed').animate({left:'0%'})

});
```

My problem now, is triggering this reverse animation with the browser back button.
Help please :( 
Thanks.

Something like this http://www.marlene-portfolio.com/

Comment: Maybe this post helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button

Comment: You want the `hashchange` event. It shouldn't matter *how* the hash has changed, but the `back` and `forward` buttons will both trigger it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate @zzzzBow.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (browser security restriction). You can tell if the user navigates away from the page (onbeforeunload, onunload fire) but you can't tell where they went (back, forward, another url etc.). So in short its not possible to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hmmm. Well thats a first...not possible. Okay. Thank you.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about. http://www.marlene-portfolio.com Click on the navigations links and then click the browser back button. See how it controls the animation.

Comment: What browswer are you using? I'm using the latest chrome