# How to listen to history events like "go back", "go next" in Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For now, I've only found a way to listen to "reload" event using:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.frameId == 0) {
    if (details.transitionType == "reload") {
      // do something
    }
  }
});
```

What about "go back" and "go next" events? I'm looking for a Firefox's `nsISHistoryListener` alternative in Chrome.

**Edit**: Submitted a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111024) to Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the window.beforeunload event to capture when a user intends to navigate to another page (which would be triggered when using the back and forward buttons).

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    // do something
};
```

There is no way to get the target destination when using `onbeforeunload`.

More info here: [Is there a cross-browser onload event when clicking the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)