# Is there any way to check the back/forward history into session in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We have utility to check the back and forward history into Mozilla [canGoBack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/en-US/XUL/Property/canGoBack) and [canGoForward](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/en-US/XUL/Property/canGoForward) .

Is there same utility present for chrome extension ?

I have searched lot but didn't find any proper clue to check the same thing for chrome extension .

If anyone has some idea then please let me know . It will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but I think that this link may help shed some light on the subject.

[How to listen to history events like "go back", "go next" in Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960602/how-to-listen-to-history-events-like-go-back-go-next-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: Hey @Wifibrain : Thanks for the link and your search ... Yes It gives me some direction , but Waiting for more efficient response .