# visiblity hidden in css not working for previous page

Tags: jquery, css

I am doing a jQuery for hotel project. `visibility hidden` is not working when i come back from next page to previous page.

This is my code:

```
$("select#rooms").live("change",function() {
  if ($('select#rooms option:selected').val()==2) {
    $("#see1").css("visibility","visible");
  } else {
    $("#see1").css("visibility","hidden");
  }
});
```

Comment: You should stop using live() - it's been deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: Just upon page load? This is only going to take effect when you change something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe on() is the new standard to use instead of live(). With regards to your issue, I believe most browsers do not preserve state when navigating back to a page. The only exception to this rule is Firefox. You could try adding an onready() handler to re-evaluate DOM objects on the page.

Comment: can you plz give example or ellaborate your answer

Comment: Try the below, referenced from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button

    history.navigationMode = 'compatible';
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        alert('test');
    });