# After clicking browser's back button, Opera browser does not fire JS or Server-side code (JSP) on page

Tags: javascript, jsp, browser, opera, back-button

I haven't this issue in the other popular browsers.  In a JSP page (let's call it Page1.jsp), I click a form which goes to a different page.  When I click Opera's Back button, it goes back to Page1.jsp, but no JavaScript or JSP code has refired.  For example,

```
<!-- Inside header tag -->
<script language="JavaScript>
  alert("Does this work in Opera?");
</script>
```

A simple alert statement does not fire.  The same goes for server-side code.  However, the other popular desktop browsers don't have a problem.

How can I fix this?

Thank you for any help.

**Update**

I should've stated -- and I apologize for this -- that Page1.jsp contains a frame/an iframe, which is where the submit form lives.  When the user submits the form, it loads a new page inside the frame/iframe.  At this point, when the user clicks the browser's back button, I see that Page1.jsp is cached, but the frame/iframe reloads.  This occurs in all the popular browsers except Opera.

Comment: Can you post a demo somewhere (JSFiddle perhaps)? I suspect it has to do with Opera's iframe security, but it would help greatly to see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kennebec: Thank you very much.  Because of your answer, I was able to do some more digging and I found a stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button) and an Opera article [here](http://www.opera.com/support/kb/view/827/), which addresses the problem:

```
history.navigationMode = "compatible"; // Opera only property
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

According to [this site](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrtiivh.php), navigationMode is only supported by Opera browsers.  So, this works perfectly and I don't have to script any unload events.  I looked up pageshow/pagehide, but it doesn't appear to be fully cross-browser compliant, and HTML5 has onpageshow/onpagehide, but I need to be cross-browser complaint and support legacy browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, most browsers behave like this, returning the browser to the state you left it 
rather than reloading a visited page 'from scratch'. It is usually a good thing, makes navigating quicker.

The browsers that 'save state' do so on unload, to override it you can replace the unload handler with one of your own-

```
<script>
alert('loaded');

onunload=function(){ return true; }
</script>
```

It is possible that a user can have some kind of autosave set on his browser to remember the state of forms between visits- for this, you may need to manually set the form fields to their defaults in the unload handler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Actually, and I'll modify the question, the form is in a frame/iframe, which is inside Page1.jsp.  So, when the user clicks the browser's back button, I see that Page1.jsp remains unchanged, but the contents of the frame/iframe is reloaded.  This happens on all popular browsers except Opera.