# Clearing textfields/textboxes when user clicks the browser's Back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, google-chrome

I have a series of textfields and textboxes that a user can fill out, then click send. If he hits the back button, I want those fields to be empty. Currently, when the user clicks back, those fields are filled with data entered before the submit.

Is there a solution for this that works in (almost) all browsers?

Comment: Here is a similar tread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the load of the page, iterate over all the inputs and set their value to an empty string.  Though, really, is there a good reason to do that to your users?  That's more of a browser feature for their convenience than a site feature.

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(input){
    input.value="";
});
```

Comment: Thanks! As to why... it's a long story but do trust it is to avoid a lot of user frustration :)

Comment: I've read that there is no "onload" event for a page loaded, I suspect because the page isn't loaded.  You may want to use the unload() event in jquery.