# Reset form on back button (safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to reset the form when the user click on the back button. Here is the code that I use.

```
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email>
...
$(function() {
   $('input[type=text]').attr('val', '');
});
```

This code is not working on Safari 6.0.2. I notice that the page load event is not even fired when the user click on the back button.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: There's no such attribute called `val`.  And getting something to fire on back button reliably cross-browser is going to be a real challenge.  Usually, there is no page `load` on `back`.

Comment: It looks like he's just resetting it on document ready, which would be called when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button/170478#170478

Comment: @Charlie, [it's really not that straightforward](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button).

Comment: @Mathieu Imbert, thanks but not working for me.

Comment: robosot, read the link in my last comment above.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `val` attribute. Use the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method instead:

```
$(function() {
   $('input[type=text]').val('');
});
```

And, you missed a quote at the `email` field:

```
<input type="text" name="email>
                              ^ Insert a quote here
```

Comment: The code in the answer is fine... too bad `document.ready` does not fire when the page is reached via the back button.

Comment: @robosot Another way to achieve empty fields is to empty the fields on unload. Does that help?

Comment: I tried with the unload. The event fires but when I click back button the fields are not reset.