# jQuery: isotope hashchange, filter and back button

Tags: jquery, html, filter, jquery-isotope, hashchange

I'm currently having some problems with the jQuery isotope plugin and hashchange function. I have a grid of divs and on page load ONLY the `grid-block-filter` divs are showing, clicking on one of the `.grid-block-filter` divs brings in the relevant content, attaching a hash to the url so the user can navigate to it from elsewhere, this all works fine, here's my example though and I'll explain my problem:
jsFiddle (with hashes): http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/vcffM/9/show 
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $container = $('#main-grid');

    if (location.hash != "") {
        var hashfilter = "." + location.hash.substr(1);
    } else {
        var hashfilter = "*";
    }

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.isotope({
            filter: hashfilter + '.nav-block',
            itemSelector: '.grid-block',
            animationEngine: 'best-available',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: 4
            }
        });
    });

    $('.grid-block-filter a').click(function () {
        var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
        var prettyselector = selector.substr(1);
        location.hash = prettyselector;
        return false;
    });

    $(window).hashchange(function () {

        if (location.hash != "") {
            var hashfilter = "." + location.hash.substr(1);
        } else {
            var hashfilter = "*";
        }


        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.isotope({
                filter: hashfilter,
                itemSelector: '.grid-block',
                animationEngine: 'best-available',
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: 4
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

If you click on `ONE FILTER` for example, this brings in the relevant content just fine, but then clicking the back button brings back ALL the content, instead of just showing the `grid-block-filter` as is when the page loads. Is there anyway to stop this happening? I can't figure it out. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user clicks the back button, then `document.ready` will not fire. This is the heart of the issue you are facing. One way would be to place your scripts at the bottom of the page and not in an onload method to ensure that they always execute.

Another way would be to take the approach of this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/170478/1026459

> If you set history.navigationMode to 'compatible' then jQuery's ready function will fire on Back button operations

```
history.navigationMode = 'compatible';
$(document).ready( function(){ /* code */ });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working the way I wanted it to, this method does work on clicking on the back button and the loading of the previous page, but as I'm using a hashchange function the page isn't being reloaded and it seems this method isn't working. I've also tried window unload, but again encounted the same problem as I'm not actually navigating away from the page?

Comment: This did not work for me in Chrome (no hashtags in my use case). Moving Isotope scripts below the Isotope divs also did not resolve.