# anchor tag href querystring back button issue

Tags: javascript, html, .net

I have several check box inputs on the page and an anchor tag.

Whenever the user checks the check boxes, I update the anchor tag href to include the query string using javascript by binding the onclick event to the check boxes.

The anchor tag navigates to a different page.

When the user clicks the browser back button, my check boxes are still checked, but the query string in the anchor tag is gone!

How do i preserve the state of the anchor tag href with the query string?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add javascript that checks the value of all checkboxes and updates the corresponding anchor tag(s). The key here is that it needs to execute on the `unload` event. That's going to be easiest with jQuery, something like:

```
jQuery(window).bind("unload", function() { // ...
```

The key is that most browsers cache the page, so you can't use standard `onload` events, as those aren't fired. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201406/259014) has a lot of added detail about that.