# Dropdownlist empty when hit back button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have a page where the model loads data and then its bound to the view.
The model obtains a List of SelectListItem from a service call and that works fine.

When the user changes the item from the first list, the 2nd list updates itself by doing an AJAX call to update the content in the list, so its a cascading thing.

Now, this works initially but when the user hits the back button, the 2nd list is empty - there are no values. The first list does have the values.

How can I ensure that the list is correctly populated when they hit the back button?

I do wire up the event and do a call in document load using JQuery but this obviously does not fire when you hit the back button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var id = 0;

            // attach onchange for ddl
            $("div[id^=hotelTypesDll_]").each(function(item) 
            { 
                var currentRowIndice = id - 1;
                $(this).find("select[id$='__HotelTypes']").each(function(currentElement) 
                {
                    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
                    $(this).change(function() 
                    { 
                        var selectedItemId = $(this).val();
                        PopulateHotelNamesList(selectedItemId, currentRowIndice);
                    });

                    currentRowIndice++;
                });
            })

            id = 0;
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser onload event and the Back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)

Comment: not a duplicate. I didn't create the thread you are referring to in addition to the question, its slightly different

Comment: You misunderstand. Duplicate doesn't mean you asked the other question, but it does mean that the other question will answer this one. That comment is a generated one from when I voted for this question to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks! anyway unfortunately the post linked does not contain what I am after