# modenizr not getting called when going back in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm seeing strange behavior with modenizr when using a mobile website.  If I go back with the browser I never seem to hit the complete function using Modenizr.  It gets called initially but when viewing another page and then clicking the back button it doesn't get called.  Is there some sort of caching happening that I need to override?

I only see "**Inititializng app**" the first time the page is loaded.

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    console.log("Loading Main...");

    loadMain();


    function loadMain() {

       console.log("Calling modenizr");

        Modernizr.load([
            {
             load: [
                    'http://localhost/js/main-test.js'
                ],
                complete: function()
                {
                    $.fn.ready(function()
                    {
                        window.App.init();

                    });
                }
            }
        ]);
    }
});
```

## main-test.js

```
(function(window, document, undefined) {

var transformProp = window.Modernizr.prefixed('transform'),
    transitionProp = window.Modernizr.prefixed('transition'),
    transitionEnd = (function() {
        var props = {
            'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend',
            'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
            'msTransition'     : 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition'       : 'transitionend'
        };
        return props.hasOwnProperty(transitionProp) ? props[transitionProp] : false;
    })(),

    hasTT = transitionEnd && transitionProp && transitionProp;

var log = function(obj)
{
    if (typeof window.console === 'object' && typeof window.console.log === 'function') {
        window.console.log(obj);
    }
};

window.App = (function()
{

    console.log("Inititializng app");

    var _init = false, app = { };

    app.init = function()
    {

        if (_init) {
            return;
        }
        _init = true;


        app.win    = $(window);
        app.docEl  = $(document.documentElement);
        app.bodyEl = $(document.body);

        app.docEl.addClass('js-ready js-' + (hasTT ? 'advanced' : 'basic'));

        var menuLinkEl = $('#menu-link'),
            menuEl = $('#menu'),
            wrapEl = $('#wrap');

        var closeMenu =function()
        {
            if (hasTT) {
                menuEl.one(transitionEnd, function(e) {
                    app.docEl.removeClass('js-offcanvas');
                });
            } else {
                app.docEl.removeClass('js-offcanvas');
            }
            app.docEl.removeClass('js-menu');
        };

        var openMenu = function()
        {
            app.docEl.addClass('js-offcanvas js-menu');
        };

        menuLinkEl.on('click', function(e)
        {
            console.log("Clicked");

            if (app.docEl.hasClass('js-menu')) {
                closeMenu();
            } else {
                openMenu();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });



    };

    return app;

})();

})(window, window.document);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser onload event and the Back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)

Comment: Check that other SO question I marked as the dup, and try adding a dummy "onunload" handler if you really want the page to reload.

Comment: This only seems to be an issue on older browser (I'm using android 2.3)

Comment: Is your "ready" handler not running, or is it just Modernizr?

Comment: I hit the ready handler each and everytime, it's just the Window.app call I only hit once

Comment: Hmm well why are you wrapping that call to the "init" function in another "ready" handler?  Since all that code only runs from a "ready" handler anyway, isn't that redundant?

Comment: (Note that I'm just kind-of guessing here, but stripping off that "ready" handler would be something I'd try if it were me, because it's so easy to do.)

Comment: good thought...I removed it but the same thing happens

Comment: According to the [Yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) page, there's some logic to prevent redundantly-loaded scripts from running twice. I wonder if that might be causing the issue?

Comment: this seems to be the case

Answer (score 0):

Add `onunload` body attribute with empty function to fix it.

Comment: No, it's just awesome hack to fire onload event in mobile browser, when user press back button. I hope it will help and in your case. And I always make it like `function () {return  true}` or something like it.

Comment: window.onunload = function () { return true }

Comment: I have almost 12 javascripts files in my footer...won't this unload them all or can I just unload the one causing issues? Thanks!

Comment: Just add this script after all and add `onunload` empty attribute to body tag.