# browsers back button location issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following script for a smooth fadeIn, fadeOut when I'm linking to subpages.

```
$("body").css("display", "none");
$("body").fadeIn(500);

$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("body").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);       
});

function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}
```

which works fine. The weird thing about this is, that the browsers back button has an issue. Lets say I'm on my `index.html` and click on a link which links to `about.html`, and try to get back to `index.html` by the back button all it shows is a blank page. It needs to refresh manually.

To make my issue clearer you can find an example [HERE](http://jobs.super-sized.de/)

**NOTE:** I experience this issue under Firefox and Safari. Chrome seems to be fine.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser onload event and the Back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the special "back/forward" cache of browsers, which stores the full state of the page.

You might want to add the `fadeIn` on the `pageshow` event.

See this answer for details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2218733/3527940

Comment: no need to say, still waiting until I can accept ;)