# body onload not working in firefox after clicking back button of browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first JSP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body onload="alert('1');">
    <form action="newjsp3.jsp" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">

        </form>
</body>
```

This is my second JSP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

When I submit form on first page and goes to second page.After clicking the back button of browser the `body onload` method works in Chrome and IE but not in firefox.Is there any way so that method works even after clicking the back button of firefox.

Comment: go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you call the function in document ready itself?

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    alert('1');
});
```