# Addclass on document.ready doesn't persist

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm styling something using the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $("div.event").closest('td').addClass('success');
```

This works great on first loading the page, but when I navigate back to the page or am redirected by a controller (this app is on Rails), the class has left the element.

For some context, this app renders events inside of a calendar styled table.  The intention is to highlight the table td if there is an event inside of it.

Any insights how I can get it to persist would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes.  What's up with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser onload event and the Back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks): "With Turbolinks pages will change without a full reload, so you can't rely on DOMContentLoaded or jQuery.ready() to trigger your code. Instead Turbolinks fires events on document to provide hooks into the lifecycle of the page."

Comment: The duplicate indicates that using `history.navigationMode = 'compatible';` should solve this problem. The reason that ready doesn't fire is because the page has been stored in the bfcache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using turbolinks, instead of:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
```

Use:

```
$(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
```

But this should only contain idempotent code.

I encourage you to check all events on the [github page](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).

Comment: When a page is loaded from the bfcache, the load event does not fire.

Comment: @TravisJ this is intended, all non idempotent stuff should only be triggered once,  and their result is cached

Comment: Which is to say that `.on("ready page:load"` will only fire once on the first page load, and not when the back button is pushed.

Comment: This works, but @TravisJ Your suggestion above of using `history.navigationMode = 'compatible';` also works.