# Jquery SlideDown work occasionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidedown

i use google chrome and the slideDown doesn't work correctly. Sometime the div go down, some time still closed, i have to refresh the page and wait when it decide to slideDown. This is the code:

HTML

```
<header>
<div class="container">
    <img src="../themes/<?= GDR_THEME ?>/images/graphic/barratop.png" />
        <div id="box_body" class="content mCustomScrollbar light" data-mcs-theme="minimal">
            <div id="box_text" >
                <form name="termini" action="core.register_1.php" method="post">
                <?php include_once "../text/regolamento.html"; ?>
                <p class="button">
                <input id="check" src="../themes/<?= GDR_THEME ?>/images/graphic/accettoff.png" 
                type="image" onMouseOver="this.src='../themes/<?= GDR_THEME ?>/images/graphic/accetton.gif'" 
                onMouseOut="this.src='../themes/<?= GDR_THEME ?>/images/graphic/accettoff.png'" />
                <input name="rego" value="ok" type="hidden" />
                </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <img src="../themes/<?= GDR_THEME ?>/images/graphic/barradown.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#box_body {
    width: 530px;
    height: 460px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: none;  
}
#box_text {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.button {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box_body").slideDown(2500);
});
```

Sometime it slide Down sometime no...
MY LINK: http://khchapterzero.altervista.org/core/core.register_0.php

Comment: Seems to work. There must be something happening that's not demonstrated in your question. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3L8a97uo

Comment: a leave my link: http://khchapterzero.altervista.org/core/core.register_0.php I told you sometime work sometime doesn't!

Comment: Only happens for me with the back button:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slideDown()` does work perfectly. The problem is, that your scripts are placed higher in the DOM index than stylesheets:

```
<script src='../themes/custom/js/jquery.min.js'></script> 
<script src='../themes/custom/js/jquery.main.js'></script> 
<script src='../themes/custom/js/jquery.scrollbar.js'></script> 
<script src='../themes/custom/js/jquery.register_0.js'></script> 
<link rel='icon' href='../themes/custom/images/engine/icon.png' type='image/x-icon' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../themes/custom/css/main.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../themes/custom/css/register_0.css' /> 
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../themes/custom/css/Scrollbar.css' />
```

This is the part of your CSS that *sometimes* keeps your `#box_body` hidden :

```
#box_body {
    ...
    display: none;  
}
```

Your `display: none;` CSS style is *sometimes* applied to the element **after** `slideDown();` because your stylesheet file is *sometimes* loaded **after** the script file.

Good practice is to place CSS stylesheets inside `<head>` tag and scripts right before close `</body>` tag.