# How to run a function on load, back, and forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, routes, cross-browser, url-routing

I've looked at a few other dated questions on this site and have found their solutions don't seem to work on modern browsers anymore.

```
var foo = function() {
  console.log('woohoo');
};
foo();
```

I want this to run everytime. I obviously have no problem running it on the first initial load but I am using url hashes to hide and show certain divs of content. When a user clicks forward and backward I would like this function to run again as well.

Comment: try this 
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () { foo(); });

Comment: @ChadHedgcockthe browsers itself. Specifically chrome right now.

Comment: @Sushil unfortunately that doesn't work. I have seen that solution in other posts but they were older.

Comment: You'll need to show some of your code that handles the forward/backward and the show/hide functionality. You could invoke `foo` from within those event handlers pretty easily, I assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers cache the page so that they load faster on back/forward. For this reason the load events are never fired and that would also be why your code isn't run again. The browser is just restoring a previous state.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button) for more details on this.

Since you are just dealing with hashes you could try binding to the [onhashchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onhashchange.asp) event and calling your method then.

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", foo);
```

If you're using a single page framework such as Angular, Backbone or one of the many others they usually provide you with a way to handle this as well so check the documentation if that's the case.

Comment: TIL about the hashChange event listener. This worked like a charm. Thank you very much.